# jax-ws with user defined parameter

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm now studying jax-ws. 
And I define a WebService:

**UserService.java**

```
@WebService
//@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT, use=Use.LITERAL)
public interface UserService {
    @WebMethod
    public User modifyUserInfo(@WebParam(name="user")User user);
    @WebMethod
    public User queryUserInfo(@WebParam(name="username")String username);   
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="UserService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Override
    public User modifyUserInfo(User user) {
        System.out.println(user);  //it prints "null"
        UserTransaction trans = new ModifyUserInfoTransaction(user);
        trans.execute();
        return trans.getResult();
    }

    @Override   
    public User queryUserInfo(String username) {
        UserTransaction trans = new QueryUserInfoTransaction(username);
        trans.execute();
        return trans.getResult();
    }   
}
```

**User.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    public enum UserType {
        Normal, Root;
    }
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private UserType usertype;

    public User() {
        usertype = UserType.Normal;
    }

    //the getters and sertters....
}
```

When I invoke queryUserInfo() in client, it works; But when invoke modifyUserInfo(),
the parameter user, is null when the server execute the function.

I use wsimport to generate the client code.

...........................................................
When I use QName and javax.xml.ws.Service rather than wsimport, it can work.

If any one Knows about this please tell me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I  configure the JAXBDataBinding  in client and server application.It works.You can try it again.